# file stream increases data base size even though it stores on file system

Tags: sql, sql-server

we know that file stream is a mechanism that is used in order to store files that are larger than 1 mb in the file system ,in order to increase streaming performance

let we assume that we have a file a that is 1.5 gb 
and we have the following table documents  which has a file stream attribute

```
 create database TryFileStream

 ALTER DATABASE TryFileStream
 ADD FILEGROUP [Common_Filestream] CONTAINS FILESTREAM 

ALTER DATABASE TryFileStream
    ADD FILE   
    (
        NAME = [Common_FileStream_1],
        FILENAME = 'C:\TryFileStream\FileStream1',
        MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED
    )
    TO FILEGROUP [Common_Filestream];


    Create Table Documents
    (
    [ID]  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER Unique ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
    content VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM   
    )
```

of course when we save 1.5 gb file in table documents ,file stream path

```
C:\TryFileStream\FileStream1 will be increased by 1.5 gb in size
```

but what surprised me that saving this file also increases the database size by 1.5 gb

so what will be the benefit of using file stream if size of data base continue to increase and backups operations will be impossible then

the only benefit that we got is quick data streaming  for user because files are stored on  the file system ,are there others ?

what should we do as small data base size is a concern ,and our system contains of alot of big files which are larger than 2 gb

Comment: How do you determine the database size?

Comment: right click on data base -> properitis->general -> size

Comment: You can back up your database without the file streams. It's just a little [involved](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bcd5dddf-5a66-42a9-acf4-a63136f3658a/backup-without-filestream-data?forum=sqldisasterrecovery).

Answer (score 1):

When you use SSMS to get the database size, a query is fired to get the size:

```
select sum(cast(gs.size as float))*convert(float,8) 
from   sys.database_files gs
```

If you fire a similar query without the aggregation:

```
SELECT  DF.type
,       DF.type_desc
,       DF.name
,       DF.size
FROM    sys.database_files AS DF
```

You should see a row with `type=2`, this is your `FILESTREAM` file.

In short, the `FILESTREAM` file is included in database size, just like the `LOG` and `DATA` files. This makes sense, since that's why you have to `ADD FILEGROUP` and `ADD FILE`.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-files-transact-sql) for more information about `sys.database_files`.